# HTML5 datetime-local (Chrome): How to input datetime in current time zone

Tags: html, timezone

I live in GMT+9, I want to input date and time that specified in my current time zone. Chrome Version 40.0.2214.93 (64-bit)

```
<input type="datetime-local" required>
```

However, if I input 12:00AM in the datetime picker,

[image]

the actual value that the element returns is `2015-01-30T00:00` (by printing out in the Chrome console), which equals 9:00AM in my time zone. Do I have to manually add 9 hours to the result? Since Chrome doesn't support `datetime` as an input type, I cannot use `datetime` as a replacement.

Comment: "Since Chrome doesn't support datetime"? What?

Comment: Please show your HTML just to make clear what element you are talking about, and specify how you entered 12:00AM. In my Chrome, there is no way to enter AM vs. PM. This may depend on browser locale, so please specify the locale (and Chrome version and platform); this sounds like a browser bug. Also note that neither `datetime-local` nor `datetime` is valid in HTML5, and they are supported by some browsers only; The more reliable approach is to have one field for date and another field for time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"2015-01-30T00:00" is exactly what you entered, so that is the result that is given back.

You said "... which equals 9:00AM in my time zone".  That would only be true if the result was in UTC - which it is not.  By the [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, it would only be presumed to be in UTC if the value ended with a trailing `Z`, such as "2015-01-30T00:00Z".

Perhaps you are feeding the value into the `Date` constructor?

```
new Date("2015-01-30T00:00")
```

In that case, the value *will* be interpreted as UTC - but that's due to a quirk of the `Date` object.  You can work around this with a bit of substitution:

```
new Date("2015-01-30T00:00".replace('T',' ').replace('-','/'))
```

Or, if you prefer cleaner code, consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which doesn't have that quirk:

```
moment("2015-01-30T00:00").toDate();  // or .format(), or other functions...
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using moment.js now.